# C# Soap Client producing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: c#, soap, nullpointerexception, client

I am writing a simple C# SOAP client to send an API request but I am receiving a NullPointerException when trying to send a value which looks like it is on a different 'level' of the API request.

I have written the following code to create an instance of the API request:

```
CreateOrderRequest createOrder = new CreateOrderRequest();
```

When using SOAP UI ,the XML request contains the following extract:

```
<data:ProductCode>RX888</data:ProductCode>
 <data:Orders>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <data:OrderLine>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:OrderAmount>157.65</data:OrderAmount>
                  <data:OrderRef>test</data:OrderRef>
               </data:OrderLine>
</data:Orders>
```

In my code, I can specify a value to use for the product code by writing the following:

```
createOrder.ProductCode = "RX888";
```

When I try to specify a value for the OrderAmount I get a nullpointer exception if I do `createOrder.OrderAmount = "5.99";

I get the same if I try to specify a value for the OrderRef too.

Can anybody help me to get this to work please?!

Comment: Callstack missing, [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) missing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your xml, it seems there *is* no `createOrder.OrderAmount`.

Your xml seems to indicate that you want to set `createOrder.OrderLine[n].OrderAmount`, where `n` is the item in your List(?) of OrderLine.

Since you are getting a NRE, the simplest explanation is that you never instantiated your List, which means it's `null`.

Adding this to the constructor of your `CreateOrderRequest` should help:

```
this.OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>();
```

Of course, adjust this for your actual definition in your `CreateOrderRequest`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The createOrder is defined by the 
    CreateOrderRequest createOrder = new CreateOrderRequest(); Also ProductCode is not on the 'Orders' level.

Comment: @REX8 Sorry, I meant _OrderAmount_ of course. I can see that `new CreateOrderRequest()`, I'm pointing out you should, in that method (it's called a constructor) do something to create that List or whetever you have your OrderLines in. Alternatively, you can do it _after_ creating that `createOrder` object (`createOrder.OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>()` or whatever.

Comment: THanks but i still cannot get it to work... If you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071610/system-nullreferenceexception-when-using-wsdl-in-c-sharp-soap-request this is a similar issue but the answers do not seem to work for my scenario.

Comment: @REX8 Just add the definition of `CreateOrderRequest` including its constructor to your question. My answer is based on assumptions and without actual information, nobody can see why this goes wrong.